# Dropbox デーモンが python-gpgme に依存しているが、Ubuntu 18.04 ではサポート外

Tags: ubuntu, dropbox

[公式サイト](https://www.dropbox.com/install)からダウンロードできる `dropbox_2015.10.28_amd64.deb` から Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Bionic に Dropbox をインストールした後、シェルで `dropbox start -i` を実行すると、Dropbox デーモンのインストールが始まります。

そのデーモンのインストール画面において、`python-gpgme` がインストールされていないという警告が出ました ("Note: python-gpgme is not installed, we will not be able to verify binary signatures.")。しかし `python-gpgme` は Ubuntu 18.04 で [obsolete になった](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pygpgme/+publishinghistory)ため、インストールすることができません。

少し調べたところ、この問題についてのバグ報告を[見つけました](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus-dropbox/+bug/1759984)。ただし 2018 年 5 月 16 日現在、状態が Confirmed から進んでいません。

Dropbox のアップデートを待つ他に、この警告を回避する方法はありませんか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

このような場合の緊急避難的な処置は、バグ報告の最後にもあるように、Ubuntu の以前のディストリビューションから該当のパッケージをダウンロードしてきてインストールすることです。アップデートされるまでの間のエラーを回避することができます。

具体的に方法を説明すると、まず、「[Ubuntu パッケージ検索](https://packages.ubuntu.com/ja/)」にいって「パッケージディレクトリを検索」で検索します。そうすると以下のような結果が表示されるので、以前のディストリビューションでは最近の artful のものを利用します。

```
Package python-gpgme

trusty (14.04LTS) (python): python wrapper for the GPGME library (Python 2)
0.3-0ubuntu3: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 powerpc ppc64el
xenial (16.04LTS) (python): python wrapper for the GPGME library
0.3-1.1: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 powerpc ppc64el s390x
artful (17.10) (python): python wrapper for the GPGME library
0.3-1.2build2: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x
```

リンクをクリックすると artful の python-gpgme に移動するので、そこから該当のアーキテクチャーのものをダウンロードします。そして、以下のようにファイルを指定して apt でインストールすることができます。

```
sudo apt install ./python-gpgme_0.3-1.2build2_amd64.deb
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！　はい、古い Ubuntu 向けにリリースされた .deb ファイルを使う方法は一時的には使えそうです。ただ、今回 obsolete となる発端となった[バグ #835174](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=835174) の Severity が serious であったため、古いリリースが安全なのかが分からず、躊躇しています。python-gpgme はセキュリティ絡みのパッケージであるため特に悩ましいです。バグの内容を見る限り脆弱性というよりかは API 変更への追従のように見えるので大丈夫なのかもしれませんが……。このあたりについて何かご存知であれば更にご教示頂けるとありがたいです。

Comment: バグ #835174についてはおっしゃられているとおりで具体的な脆弱性がないこと、また、Dropboxのソフトがクライアント側で直接攻撃にさらされる場所ではないことから、危険性がそれほど高いことはないと思います。あとは自己責任の世界なので、早くアップデートされることを期待したいですね。

Comment: 2019/12/07にバグ #835174 が "Fix Released" の状態になりました。どうやら修正されたようです。